# NSubstitute Received() responding to multiple calls

Tags: nsubstitute

I have an object that I've faked with NSubstitute that has a method on it that gets called twice. I'd like to verify that the method has actually been called twice (and only twice). I've poked around the docs and Google with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This currently isn't supported in NSubstitute 1.2.1 (the feature is implemented in a branch, and will make it to next release).

An alternative for now is to use `substitute.ReceivedCalls()` which will return an enumerable you can query. Another option is to use `When..Do` to increment a counter whenever the method is called, and assert that the counter ends up at 2.

***Update 2011-11-19:** This is supported in NSubstitute 1.3.0, using `Received(int)`. It is documented on the [Checking received calls](http://nsubstitute.github.com/help/received-calls/) page.*